# What is the exact difference between Recession , Depression and Financial Crisis

Tags: markets

I want to know the exact difference between Recession, Depression and Financial Crisis.

Comment: I know about investing . I'm not a noob. Just need to know about financial markets.

Comment: When the markets drop, for you it's a recession.  For me, it's a depression ;->)

Comment: We have an [economics.se] site for questions like this.

Comment: Ok thanks, i didn't know about that. Will use that site for questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [recession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_depression) *was* defined by a drop in GDP over two consecutive quarters. Now it has a more nebulous definition:

> In the United States, it is defined as "a significant decline in economic activity spread across the market, lasting more than a few months, normally visible in real GDP, real income, employment, industrial production, and wholesale-retail sales".

A [depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_depression) does not have a strict definition, but a proposed definition is a recession that lasts 2 or more years or a drop in GDP of 10% or more.

There is no strict definition for a [financial crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_crisis). It could be a stock market crash, a housing bubble, or sudden high inflation.

One differentiator between these is that recession/depression are determined by the production of the national economy as a whole (generally measured by GDP), but a financial crisis is specific to the value of financial instruments, but can *affect* the economy through secondary effects (e.g. businesses cannot borrow money affordably so their production decreases)

Comment: You know man the first sentence is just "wrong" ... inasmuch as https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/recession.asp  ... *"However, the National Bureau of Economic Research (NBER), which officially declares recessions, says the two consecutive quarters of decline in real GDP are not how it is defined anymore."*

Comment: @Fattie Thanks - I hadn't realized that the definition had changed.

Comment: "even drunks can help with internet links"

Answer (score -1):

There are **absolutely no** firm, defined, "scientific" meanings of these words.

You can use them any way you want.

They are simply descriptive.

It is absolutely commonplace that (say, on a talk show) people will disagree about whether or not "it is a recession".

Some particular bodies may have some written definition that that body uses. In which case you would have to ask about that specific entity.

(But note that all numbers in economics are made up, or a guess. "Inflation," say, is just a changing list of items one can buy [anyone can write a different list and get a different number], "unemployment" has dozens of different possible meanings, and so on.)

Comment: I need a difference even a simplified or just any correct difference will work for me

Comment: Google is your friend.  It's better than Alexa.

Comment: ok thanks a lot

Comment: "You can use them anyway you want." So I can use "recession" to mean a sharp upturn in the market? I know what you are *trying* to say, but you don't need to exaggerate so much to make your point.

Comment: I get your point, but, indeed the market does sometimes spike up when (say) jobs is down or hunger is up.